# Convert image with uncommon aspect ratio without stretching the image

Tags: osx, conversion, imagemagick, jpeg

I have found a map online, I like to print out (see link to original here: http://collections.lib.uwm.edu/digital/collection/agdm/id/4614/).

However, it has an uncommon(?) aspect ratio, which I would like to adjust to a ratio that fits common aspect ratios, like 4:3 or quadratic (or what ever is more suitable for the aspect ratio of the map).

On a Mac, how can I convert the map (with `imagemagick`?) to jpg or tiff (which ever is more lossless) to have a common aspect ratio without stretching and losing as few as possible from the map.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: With imagemagick, of course. It runs on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can do it with `imagemagick` which you can install via *macports* or *brew*.

In OS X you can do it over *Preview* application too.

1. Show Markup Toolbar in *Preview* application:

[image]

2. Chose *Resize image* from opened toolbar:

[image]

3. Set necessary size:

[image]

Size in my screenshot was taken from *[Aspect ratio calculator](https://calculateaspectratio.com)* (I'm not sure if it will be useful for you, but it's a good start point of adjusting image procedure for your needs):

[image]